# How does Java interpret keyword?

Tags: java

I am reading java, so by surfing net and resources I came to know about that java define keyword in java specification. But I need a bit more clearance.
 So what I want to know is that as everything we use like methods or classes is defined in some java package. But how does it resolve definition about keywords like int, float etc? How does everything work when it comes to keywords?

To be more clear let say if I have to use Scanner class method then I have to import java.util.* package and then only I can use Scanner class method by creating its object and then compiler check that whether all the required definition is available to it. So what happens in the case of primitive data type and keyword?
Who actually provide the information, does it is a compiler or JVM and how.
Bit confusing for me.

Comment: They are defined in the spec and checked by the compiler. Besides that your question isn't really clear for me.

Comment: Thomas I have added the bit more information to make it clear. So hope this will clear my context.

Comment: You are basically asking how a compiler works. Too broad.

Comment: A compiler likely keeps something like a lookup table to map names to types (and methods, and other stuff). Custom types are added to the lookup table when references to the containing packages are added. You can think of imports as creating temporary "shortcuts" in the lookup table. Built-in types like `int` are probably inserted to the lookup table from the start.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis You want to say that it is the lookup table where all the reserved word and primitive types definitions are  available and compiler make reference to this table whenever it comes across the definition.

Comment: @code_legend Not all the reserved keywords, no. But the built-in types (whose names are a subset of the reserved keywords) could be.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Ok, what about rest of reserved words. And is there any link or resource available which can clear my doubt with a full explanation.

Comment: @code_legend The rest of the reserved words are generally expected based on a number of patterns. For example, before the word "class", the compiler expects to (maybe) see words like "public", "final", etc. That's all defined in the grammar of the language ([example of one possible definition of Java's grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4)) and the grammar is then fed to the compiler using a method that depends on how the compiler is constructed in the first place. The part of the compiler you're looking for is the *lexer* (and maybe the *parser* too).

Comment: Must read few books about translation background, is impossible to give full theory in short post. No one answers can be deep and correct, because of beginners level. BTW You mix many things in question (recognition, parsing, AST, dynamic linking, importing )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keywords are special words in the grammar of a language. A keyword has a special meaning in a language. Personally I like to distinguish more between reserved words and keywords and built-in types but that's just me. (I wouldn't call `int` a keyword for example, it's just a built-in type so at best it's a reserved word).

These things are treated differently by the compiler. The compiler knows how to handle `public`, `int`, `void`, `class` etc.

**Update**

Actually it's not true that you need to import the package to use the scanner:

```
public void M() throws FileNotFoundException {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(new File(""));
}
```

This is a valid snippet of code. `import` just import things into your *namespace*.  If you have for example a `java.util.Scanner` and a `com.business.Scanner` you can not import them both because you now have a conflict in your namespace: You have two `Scanner`s.

`Scanner` is NOT part of the java *language*. `int` is. As far as your compiler is concerned there's no such thing as `Scanner` but there are such things as `int`, `double`. In essence: The *definitions* for these keywords are built into the compiler. Primitive data types are built-in types the compiler knows about. You do not have to tell the compiler what a `double` is, it just knows. However, you do have to tell your compiler what a `Scanner` is. (Of course, if you're writing a compiler you do have to teach the compiler you're writing what a double is).

Keywords like `while`, `public` are different because they are not data types. They are part of the grammar (and semantics) of the language. The compiler knows how to treat these. If it sees a `while` it produces machine code (or bytecode in java) that loops as long as a certain condition is true.

Think of a simple language with a grammar like this:

```
Program: <Identifier>, 'says', <Text>
Identifier: Character | Character, Identifier
Text: '"', [Character], '"'
```

This looks confusing but essentially this grammar means that a Program (sentence) starts with a *Name*, is then followed by *says* and then followed by *Text*. In this case `says` IS a keyword. It has a special meaning in the language. For example the compiler will produce code that displays the text on screen when it sees such a program with `says` in it.

Comment: nice explanation in simple words but I want the bit more detailed explanation.

Comment: (I've updated my answer a little bit yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler follows these simple rules when it finds an *identifier*:

1. Looks it in the list of built-in keywords (like `public`, `abstract`, `return`, etc). If it is included in that list, then it is a keyword.
2. If not found, same with built-in types (like `int`, `char`, `double`, `float`, etc).
3. If not found, looks it in current scope's definitions, in this order:

   - Within the current block.
   - Within the current method.
   - Within the current class or interface.
   - Within the current package.
4. If not found, looks it in the definitions imported in the current source (through the `import` declarations).

As you can see, the built-in types and reserved keywords have always priority, no matter the current scope or declared imports.

Comment: agree at "popularisation" level, this is level of  question, OK. But this speech isn't absolutely strict at "pro" level. Impossible to draw all "pro" without asker knowledge about languages, grammars etc

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. I didn't mean to write a doctoral thesis about the subject. I think that is enough explainatory for the level of the OP. But, just for curiosity, what catches do you find about it?

Comment: My thinking is in way like mulitlayers compilers are build (lexer/ parser / .../ code generator /VM). Keywords are processed in lexer etc ... In most grammars I can imagine, keyword not fit in 'identifiers'. BUT Your answer is OK in context of beginner question, is impossible to give full theory in short post.

Comment: @JacekCz You are right: That was kind a shortcut to "fix" keywords processing along with built-in types and custom identifier processing. Actually, an identifier is recognized often because it has a reserved keyword before. :-)